# Ubuntu 18.04 installer - select seed file based on condition

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, iso, preseed, isolinux

I have an ISO installation of ubuntu 18.04 which has a `txt.cfg` file in it.

the `txt.cfg` has 4 options in it, and a preseed file is selected based on the option chosen:

```
label option1
  menu option1
  kernel /install/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/option1.seed vga=788 initrd=/install/initrd.gz ...

label option2
  menu option2
  kernel /install/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/option2.seed vga=788 initrd=/install/initrd.gz ...
```

each of the seed files (in this example, `option1.seed` & `option2.seed`) sets up the partitions differently using `d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string`.

Instead of the user having to choose the suitable partitioning option for him, I wrote a bash script which according to different parameters of the machine (CPU, RAM, etc..) can tell which option is suitable.

How can I run a bash script as part of the `.cfg` file or somewhere in the `.seed` file?

I saw usages of `d-i preseed/late_command` and `d-i preseed/early_command` but not sure how do use them.

Comment: `d-i preseed/early_command` can be used to run shell commands before the `preseed` process begins and you can deduce the other command. Is there some help for you here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1080528/531149?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. In the link you sent, `late_command` is being used and not `early_command`

Comment: Alright, you're welcome. But have you tried it, nevertheless? Also, if you read my comment above well, I concluded the first sentence with `... and you can deduce the other command.`, just to note that the `preseed` process remains the `preseed` process and the `early_command` and/or `late_command` play their own described role(s) as well... I don't know if you understand me clearly..?

Answer (score 1):

I think the `txt.cfg` is a config for [SYSLINUX/ISOLINUX](https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Config).  I don't think it is capable of the dynamic options you are looking for.

I suggest using `early_command` to copy an appropriate recipe to a specific path used by the preseed `expert_recipe_file` option.  The same preseed file is used for all installs, but the recipe file can be chosen based on whatever logic is desired.

For example, I will use options similar to these in my preseed file to choose either a UEFI or BIOS based recipe.

```
d-i preseed/early_command string \
  if [ -d /sys/firmware/efi/ -o -d /proc/efi ]; then \
    cp /cdrom/recipe_efi  /run/my_recipe ; \
  else \
    cp /cdrom/recipe_bios /run/my_recipe ; \
  fi ;

d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe_file string /run/my_recipe
```